# Magento 2 - How to add custom attribute to sales/order/view?

Tags: magento2, attributes, adminhtml, sales-order

How can I add a custom field to sales/order/view in adminhtml?

I want to save a tracking number related to the order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check below code.**

```
<?php
// Load the order
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
    ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', '000000001');
//OR
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
    ->load('1');

// Check if order has already shipped or can be shipped
if (!$order->canShip()) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        __('You can\'t create an shipment.')
    );
}

// Initialize the order shipment object
$convertOrder = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
$shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

// Loop through order items
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
// Check if order item is virtual or has quantity to ship
    if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
        continue;
    }

    $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();

// Create shipment item with qty
    $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);

// Add shipment item to shipment
    $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
}

// Register shipment
$shipment->register();

$data = array(
    'carrier_code' => 'ups',
    'title' => 'United Parcel Service',
    'number' => 'TRACKNO1', // Replace with your tracking number
);

$shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

try {
// Save created shipment and order
    $track = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory')->create()->addData($data);
    $shipment->addTrack($track)->save();
    $shipment->save();
    $shipment->getOrder()->save();

// Send email
    $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
        ->notify($shipment);

    $shipment->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        __($e->getMessage())
    );
}
```

Thanks and Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has standard functionality for saving tracking number on the order. However, this information is associated with a shipment, so to use this you will have to create a shipment for the order.

To programmatically add it would have the same effect as clicking on Add Tracking Number and manually filling in the information on the order view.

[image]

If you add that you will not get information on the sales order view page but a link on that page to the tracking information:

[image]

Clicking on Track Order will open a popup:

[image]

Code looks like this, I added it in a Controller in this example but of course it will most likely be somewhere else. This assumes the shipment is already created for the order in question.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\AddTrackingNumber\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentRepository;

class Index implements ActionInterface
{
    private ShipmentTrackInterfaceFactory $trackFactory;
    private ShipmentRepository $shipmentRepository;

    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        ShipmentTrackInterfaceFactory $trackFactory,
        ShipmentRepository $shipmentRepository
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->trackFactory = $trackFactory;
        $this->shipmentRepository = $shipmentRepository;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = 5;
        $trackingNumber = "XYZOEOXOE";

        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterface $tracking */
        $tracking = $this->trackFactory->create()
            ->setTitle("My title")
            ->setTrackNumber($trackingNumber)
            ->setDescription("Some description")
            ->setCarrierCode('flatrate_flatrate')
            ->setOrderId($order->getEntityId());

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment $shipment */
        $shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();
        $shipment->setTracks([$tracking]);
        $this->shipmentRepository->save($shipment);
    }
}
```

If you do not want to create a shipment or use this built in functionality. You can add an additional column to sales_order called e.g. trackingnumber, then use $order→setTrackingnumber($trackingNumber), then $orderRepository→save($order) to persist. Than make appropriate adjustments to sales_view_index.xml combined with template updates. however, it makes most sense to use the built in functionality whenever possible.

Good Luck!